# Parallelisms in Azure Data factory v2 copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are implementing solution to achieve similar functionality as of ssis packages to copy data from one database to another (on-premise to azure SQL). In SSIS we have option to setup parallel processing in different ways. We can also transfer data in chunks.
Similarly, which is the best way to achieve parallelisms in Azure Data Factory version 2? Please consider scenario of transferring data for only 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Copy Activity Performance and Tuning Guide for ways to optimize transferring data into the Cloud with ADF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance

Comment: I have already gone thru this article and it is good informative article. But, there are various way of doing parallelism. which one you would suggest?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the "Parallel Copy" section and the writeBatchSize parameter